# Python - matplotlib - imshow - How to influence displayed value of unzoomed image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to search outliers in more or less homogeneous images representing some physical array. The images have a resolution which is much higher than the screen resolution. Thus every pixel on screen originates from a block of image pixels. Is there the possibility to customize the algorithm which calculates the displayed value for such a block? Especially the possibility to either use the lowest or the highest value would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Scipy provides several such filters.  To get a new image (new) whose pixels are the maximum/minimum over a w*w block of an original image (img), you can use:

```
new = scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(img, w)
new = scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter(img, w)
```

scipy.ndimage.filters has [several other filters available](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html).

If the standard filters don't fit your requirements, you can roll your own.  To get you started here is an example that shows how to get the minimum in each block in the image.  This function reduces the size of the full image (img) by a factor of w in each direction.  It returns a smaller image (new) in which each pixel is the minimum pixel in a w*w block of pixels from the original image.  The function assumes the image is in a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
def condense(img, w):
    new = np.zeros((img.shape[0]/w, img.shape[1]/w))
    for i in range(0, img.shape[1]//w):
        col1 = i * w
        new[:, i] = img[:, col1:col1+w].reshape(-1, w*w).min(1)
    return new
```

If you wanted the maximum, replace min with max.

For the condense function to work well, the size of the full image must be a multiple of w in each direction.  The handling of non-square blocks or images that don't divide exactly is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You probably want to use the `ndimage` version of this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter

Comment: Hi John and tcaswell,

Comment: Hi John and tcaswell, thanks for your answer.
Do you know whether I can combine this easily with the Standard GUI used with imshow? Or do I need to implement it myself if I want an interactive GUI where upon zoom/unzoom this filter is applied automatically?